# DD-WRT SNMP OID for network traffic

Tags: snmp, dd-wrt

I am looking for the OID on DD-WRT to monitor my interface traffic on LAN/WAN/WLAN. I've looked, but can't find any MIB's for DD-WRT. Can someone point me in the right direction? I've  snmpwalk'ed the router, but I don't know which one is network traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `IfInOctets` and `IfOutOctets` values.

The OIDs of these are well-documented on the DD-WRT [wiki](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/SNMP#Known_OID.C2.B4s_via_SNMP).

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe I hadn't stumbled upon that yet.